# Flutter shared prefernce return NULL

Tags: flutter, dart

I have next piece of flutter code, to get shared preference key-value

I do understand why **_blueUriInit** is always NULL

[image]

Comment: did you set any value to that `key` before calling `getValue` ?

Comment: yes,  String _blueUriInit = "";

Comment: show the method showing how you're saving the data into the SharedPrefs.

Comment: I will try edit now my question with full code

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: code too long, stack overflow does not let me do it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are forgot to provide the value for that key before call to get its value, you need to first assign value to it first:

```
Future<bool> saveData(String key, dynamic value) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.setString(key, value);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
void initState() {
   saveData('blueUri', 'test');

   setState(() {
     _blueUriInit = getValue('blueUri');
   });
   super.initState();
}
```

now next time you open your app, `getValue` should return you `test`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create this function for setting value

```
static setUserID(String key, String value) async {
   final SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   preferences.setString(key, value);
}
```

Use case :

```
await SharedValue.setUserID("Email", "demo@gmail.com");
```

And For getting value from shared preference you can use this function

```
static Future<String?> getUserID(String key) async {
    final SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getString(key);
}
```

Use case :

```
userName = await SharedValue.getUserID("Email");
```

Answer (score 0):

> First you need to setString with key and value (name is key)

```
Future setValue() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString("name", "Hitarth");
}
```

> getString with key (here i took "name" as key)

```
Future getValue(String key) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String value = prefs.getString(key) ?? "NULL";
  return value;
}
```

> store in variable callin getValue

```
void initState() {
  setState(() {
    _blueUriInit = getValue("name");
  });
  super.initState();
}
```